# How can I PIVOT and COUNT in Standard SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I would like to pivot and count the following data in Standard SQL (using Google Add-On OWOX BI with Big Query):

[image: INPUT]

so that it outputs in standard sql as the below:

[image: RESULTS]

So I would want to select the itemsku and pivot based off of the "Reason."

Can't figure this out, thank you!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT itemsku,
       COUNTIF(reason = 'BIG') AS big,
       COUNTIF(reason = 'NONE') AS none,
       COUNTIF(reason = 'SMALL') AS small
FROM `project.dataset.table`
GROUP BY itemsku
```

You can test, play with above using dummy data from your question as below

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 1010101 itemsku, 'BIG' reason UNION ALL
  SELECT 1010101, 'BIG' UNION ALL
  SELECT 13333, 'NONE' UNION ALL
  SELECT 13333, 'NONE' UNION ALL
  SELECT 14444, 'NONE' UNION ALL
  SELECT 14444, 'NONE' UNION ALL
  SELECT 14444, 'SMALL' 
)
SELECT itemsku,
       COUNTIF(reason = 'BIG') AS big,
       COUNTIF(reason = 'NONE') AS none,
       COUNTIF(reason = 'SMALL') AS small
FROM `project.dataset.table`
GROUP BY itemsku
-- ORDER BY itemsku
```

with result as

```
Row     itemsku     big     none    small    
1       13333       0       2       0    
2       14444       0       2       1    
3       1010101     2       0       0
```

Comment: great. consider voting up the answer. this is equally important to do to recognize helpful answers

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select itemsku,
       sum(case when reason = 'BIG' then 1 end) as big,
       sum(case when reason = 'SMALL' then 1 end) as small,
       sum(case when reason = 'NONE' then 1 end) as none
from t
group by itemsku;
```

If you want `0`s instead of `NULL`s, then add `else 0` to the case expressions.